# Reading json file into pandas dataframe is very slow

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file of size less than 1Gb.I am trying to read the file on a server that have 400 Gb RAM using the following simple  command:

```
df = pd.read_json('filepath.json')
```

However this code is taking forever (several hours) to execute,I tried several suggestions  such as

```
df = pd.read_json('filepath.json', low_memory=False)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_json('filepath.json', lines=True)
```

But none have worked. How come reading 1GB file into a server of 400GB be so slow?

Comment: Did you try `import json; d=json.load(open('filepath.json')); df=pd.DataFrame(d)`?

Comment: Is your json essentially a list of dictionaries?  Is it one dictionary per line?  Do you need all the attributes or just some of them?

Comment: Even though `pandas.read_json` is not fast, I don't think it will take several hours (It's just a wild guess). I suspect that your table has too many columns, or `pandas.read_json` is reading it that way. pandas is terrible at handling tables with too many columns. For example, `pd.DataFrame([range(100000)])` will take more than one second to create. Please check how many rows and columns your table has.

Comment: Thanks I think the problem was with reading directly using read_json. while @tomerar suggestion worked in few seconds!

Comment: @Youcef, what was the solution that from @tomera?

Comment: You need to open the file using python reader : With open('filepath', 'r') as f , then use:  json.loads(f.read())

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chunking can shrink memory use.
I recommend Dask Library can load data in parallel.